# Is it possible to run regression with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

For each test I have created a Java class. Now I am wondering how to run all these test once. I mean how to execute regression test and see result in WebDriver.
Is it possible in Selenium WebDriver?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium cannot execute your tests, it just provides the way for you to interact the browser.
Since you mentioned that you're using Java, then you need to use some unit testing framework like JUnit.

That will also take care of the other stuff mentioned by you, the test results.

Comment: Just to add, any automation test framework can be used. for example TestNG can also be used

Comment: thank you guys.Is their any limitation to adding number of test in JUnit test suit?and which one is more preferable to use JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: There is no limitation as how many tests you can have, as for JUnit vs TestNG, I prefer using TestNG, as it offers you some extra stuff compared to JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly run that Java as well and via some unit testing framework like `Junit/TestNg`

To run in Java, write one Class with `main()` method, call all the methods you want to execute inside main class and execute `main` class as a Java executor. It will execute all your test classes.